# Php: Start session In one api and destroy in another api

Tags: php, api, session

I am starting session in one api using session_start and want to end session in another api. Both API are written in different PHP files.

Can I destroy PHP session created in first API from second API? I am not able to destroy session from second API using session_destroy. I am getting error session uninitialized.

Also can I give timeout/cookie to session?

Answer (score 1):

```
// Initialize the session.
// If you are using session_name("something"), don't forget it now!
session_start();

// Unset all of the session variables.
$_SESSION = array();

// If it's desired to kill the session, also delete the session cookie.
// Note: This will destroy the session, and not just the session data!
if (ini_get("session.use_cookies")) {
    $params = session_get_cookie_params();
    setcookie(session_name(), '', time() - 42000,
        $params["path"], $params["domain"],
        $params["secure"], $params["httponly"]
    );
}

// Finally, destroy the session.
session_destroy();
```

Comment: It seems you're creating and destroying session In same PHP API/file. I need to create session in one api and destroy in from other PHP API i.e. Both my API's are written in separate PHP file.

Answer (score 0):

Did you start the session on the second page?  You have to start it before you destroy it.

```
session_start();
session_unset();
session_destroy();
```

Try that.

Comment: I had started session on hit of first API. I am generating OTP in first API. After first API, I have to hit second API to verify the OTP. I was creating session on hit of first api and wanted to destroy session after second api executes completely.